# Waiting for an event to finish before continuing in for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, events, unity-game-engine, coroutine

So I've been stuck at this part for a while.
I am writing a project where I have about 12 rounds of the same test.
So basiclly I want the same functionallity just with a different avatar each time.

There is an event that fires, when it fires it calls a function named FinishTest
I want the loop to continue only when FinishTest is fired and finishes.

```
for (int i = 0;  i < numberOfAvatars; i++) {
    StartTest(avatars[i]); // This is not really relevent to the question
    //Wait until the FinishTest event is finished before continuing the loop
}
```

FinishTest is activated when there is a trigger between my model and some object.
There is no way FinishTest will finish before startTest because StartTest basiccly instansiate the model and thats it, so I don't think there has to be some way to make sure StartTest finishes before FinishTest.

What's inside the functions does not really matter but why not :

```
private void  StartTest(GameObject avatar) {
        Instantiate(avatar, new Vector3(2f,2f,2f), Quaterion.identity));
}

private void FinishTest()
{
    testsResults[testNumber] = new TestResult(avatarsName, holdingObject); 
       testsResults[testNumber].setTimeUntilAvatarGotShot(string.Format("{0:F2}",timer)
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Comment: When you say event, you really mean an event or you just want to wait for each `StartTest` call to finish before continuing the `for` loop?

Comment: there is a seperate event, when the event fires it calls a function in the same script that is called FinishTest. I don't know why I detailed so much about StartTest when the real issue is FinishTest

Comment: Where is that even changed? Why not modify question and include this?

Comment: Edited to avoid confuision

Comment: Show us how your `StartTest` event is declared then where it is invoked. Also the code in your question, are they in a coroutine function?  Right now, you do not have any code that has anything to do with problem in your question. This reduces the chances of you getting a reasonable answer.

Comment: Edited again, altough what's inside the function does not add much to the question, this is why i didמ't wrote it in the first place :)

Comment: as a basic you need to learn about coroutines, StartCoroutine and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool TestFinished;
IEnumerator RunTest() {
    for (int i = 0;  i < numberOfAvatars; i++) {
        TestFinished = false;
        StartTest(avatars[i]); // This is not really relevent to the question

        //Wait until the FinishTest event is finished before continuing the loop
        while (!TestFinished) yield return null;
    }
}

private void FinishTest()
{
    testsResults[testNumber] = new TestResult(avatarsName, holdingObject); 
    testsResults[testNumber].setTimeUntilAvatarGotShot(string.Format("{0:F2}",timer);
    TestFinished = true;
}
```

then you `StartCoroutine(RunTest())` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thank you :) wokred out great. My mistake was doing a for and than a courutine instead of the for loop inside the IEnumertor